# Identify whether the app is installed for the first time using Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am working on a cross platform app using Titanium Appcelerator.

I want my app to find out if the application is installed for the first time on that particular device.

How can I do it using Ti.App.Properties?

Can anyone tell how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, e.g.:

```
if( !Titanium.App.Properties.hasProperty( 'firstTime' ) ) {           
        // set the property for next time
        Ti.App.Properties.setBool( 'firstTime' , false );
        // do something
}
```

The properties will be wiped if the user uninstalled the application.

Comment: would be much better like `if( !Titanium.App.Properties.hasProperty('firstTime') )`